# How to read colored text from a Microsoft Word document

Tags: python, python-3.x, doc

I am using Python 3.4 on Windows 7. I have a Microsoft Word (.doc) file which contains data.
Some portion of that data is colored in red and underlined as well.

How can I extract those particular lines?

Comment: any help guys...m stuck in this...cant read red colored characters in the document

Answer (score 0):

See if anything listed on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=microsoft%20word&submit=search) helps.  Or try websearch for 'python microsoft word'.

Comment: PyPI didn't help...did websearch before posting smthng here...thnxx anyways